# Which does RailsAdmin initialize models from ("Uninitialized Constant" Error)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse, rails-admin

I am trying to use RailsAdmin and am getting an `Uninitialized Constant TableNameX` error. I did indeed misspell `TableNameX` originally.

I figured that if I went and changed all the mis-spelled spots the problem would resolve itself. It hasn't, so I seem to be missing a spot--but my searches within Eclipse are not turning anything up!

Which folder/folder would RailsAdmin be reading from?

Comment: Define "change all the misspelled spots"; was there a migration involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your trace look like?

Also have you looked into /config/initializers/rails_admin.rb to see if your TableNameX is there and you simply forgot to change it? :)

P.S: And don't forget to restart the server, initializers only run once at the server bootup.

Comment: Yep, forgot to restart server…ah, well. Thanks!